# Fitting a survival curve with survfit()

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

I have a survival data, `df`, as shown below:

```
df <- structure(list(time_to_event = c(369L, 4597L, 2154L, 4426L, 823L, 
4248L, 1045L, 4186L, 1305L, 1960L, 3905L, 5L, 3840L, 3802L, 3730L, 
280L, 3678L, 81L, 59L, 3360L, 3318L, 3142L, 2912L, 2909L, 2873L, 
2847L, 2843L, 2819L, 44L, 2677L, 2647L, 2569L, 2507L, 27L, 2372L, 
1771L, 1708L, 1131L, 1618L, 1597L, 1303L, 1254L, 1242L, 386L, 
1150L, 1113L, 1078L, 1036L, 1008L, 972L, 118L, 927L, 495L, 781L, 
772L, 735L, 496L, 469L, 428L, 413L, 270L, 959L), event = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-62L), class = "data.frame")
```

I fitted a survival function below:

I don't quite get why it gives `NA` for the summary statistics, median and 95% CI

```
survfit(Surv(time_to_event, event) ~ 1, data = df)
# Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time_to_event, event) ~ 1, data = df)
# 
# n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
# 62      15      NA      NA      NA
```

I thought it may due to missing values in the original dataset, but there is no missingness.

The `lung` dataset in `survival` works perfectly fine:

```
survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
# Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
# 
# n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
# 228     165     310     285     363
```

Comment: Only 15 out of 62 (24%) have experienced the event. So it's not surprising that the median time to event is undefined. In the lung data, the figure is 72% and the median time to experiencing death is 310 days. This means that 50% of the sample had died at day 310.

Comment: @Edward So, is it still worth looking at this data for survival analysis? Do you know how the median is calculated here? I tried `median(lung$time) # [1] 255.5` and `median(lung$time[which(lung$status == 2)]) # [1] 226` - they give different values

Comment: No, it's the Kaplan-Meier estimate, not the crude. You need to include all of the sample, even those that are censored. Find a textbook or source on survival analysis. Whether the data is still worth analysing is a question for another site, not SO.